# HL7 2.xml transport, HL7 3 transport, standard XML transport = SOAP?

Tags: xml, soap, hl7, transport

I am developing a small server with HL7 2.x support.

I've finished the MLLP reader (which accepts the HL7 2.x default, and now it is time to figure out how to accept HL7 2.xml.

However, I can find no information whatsoever on what transport is used for this!

I know it is generally less used, but surely someone must have implemented it at least once? How are you transporting the XML ?

The default is wrapped in MLLP (consists of a start byte and a couple end-bytes) ... SOAP strikes me as the obvious choice for the XML version of HL7 2.x, but I guess it also could be wrapped in MLLP. However, I'd prefer to know what is the standard.

Also, while i'm on the general topic:

How are HL7 3 messages wrapped ?
Is there a usual case ... in general XML messages, when sent over a network, are transported using xxxxxx (again.. , SOAP?)
thanks for any replies!

sean

p.s. Yes I am intentionally asking for HL7 2 (not 3) xml. Encoding as described here:
www.hl7.org/documentcenter/public/wg/xml/drafts/v2xml1mlbb.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the message format for the delivery mechanism. MLLP is certainly exceedingly common for HL7 2.x (enough that I've had clients just say "we send the messages via TCP/IP"), but it is just a message, you can send it any way you choose. I've two cases where the exchange of v2.x messages is partly file-system based (FTP/S in one case, network directory pickup in another).

Similarly for HL7 3, you can send the XML any way you want. I agree that SOAP seems natural given the XML format of the message, but I've honestly not had any client use the v3 format yet. I've also not had many clients "get" the notion of delivering HL7 messages via SOAP or a web service in general.

To reinforce my first point, if you look at an interface engine like Mirth Connect, you will see that the delivery mechanism is kept as an independent decision from the message format. I can deliver via file, LLP, FTP, Web Service, etc... and the message can be v2, v3, EDI, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It wasn't so much that I am confusing the delivery mechanism (transport) for the message format. Just that, given my experience so far, involving a good number of european and north American hospitals, when it comes to HL7 v2, MLLP over TCP/IP seems to be the most common case, with simple file import/export being minimally used (more often by smaller clinics).

Comment: sorry.. out time on last comment: 

With that in mind, I expected to find a 'trend' or a more common transport method for the other formats, HL7v3 + others (In my little proof of concept, I do not wish to implement all possible transport methods... just the most common 1 or 2). 

So, what I should have asked, simply, is, what is the most common method for transport, over TCP/IP for :

1. HL7v3
2. XML messages in general

thanks!

Comment: p.s. Not sure why you replaced all my references to Hl7 2.xml with "HL7 3/xml". This is not (only) what I was asking for. HL7 2.xml is apparently used in some hospitals, where they wish to send HL7 2, not in the most common 'default' format, but in its XML encoded form.

Comment: Sorry for the spurious edit. It wasn't clear in the original that you were referring to v2.xml vs. v3.